# Forecasting revenue using Monte Carlo Simulation in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to forecast revenue for a bank using Monte Carlo Simulation.

Revenue is defined as-
Revenue=A * B * C * D

I am absolutely new to this method. From what I have read, I am planning to check the distribution for each of the independent variables (A,B,C,D) using fitdistplus package in R. Then, for each of these independent variable, I will generate random numbers basis the best distribution. Is this the right way to go about this problem?

Also, how do I run the simulation? Any help or references on how to proceed will be really appreciated.

Comment: You could bootstrap this.

Comment: So after generating random numbers for these 4 variables, I should simulate using bootstrapping?

Comment: Apparently, you don't know how bootstrapping works. I'd suggest doing some research on your own first.

Comment: So from what I can understand, I can use bootstrapping to resample my historical data specified number of times (unlike Monte Carlo simulation which generated random numbers basis historical data). For each of these samples, I can calculate my revenue and check for the occurrence of revenue across samples.